# How to place a figure wrapped into the text after importing from inkscape?

Tags: positioning, wrapfigure

I import a figure from SVG and insert it in my book. The environment `wrapfigure` doesn't work properly. LaTeX places it under the text:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{6.5cm}
\input{minimal_figure}
\caption{Name of the figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

`minimal_figure.tex` is the following:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape 0.91_64bit, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'Derivative_of_a_function.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{252bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.95238095)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{minimal_figure.pdf}}%
    \put(0.5476904,0.79852081){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ F $}}%
    \put(1.26829466,1.74983366){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{minipage}{0.1122392\unitlength}\raggedright \end{minipage}}}%
    \put(1.28849768,1.68697974){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0.22597206,0.49316367){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ \Delta y$} }%
    \put(0.03709135,0.67054268){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ f(x) $}}%
    \put(0.01307867,0.29686375){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ f(x_0) $}}%
    \put(0.50275777,0.18562398){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ \Delta x $}}%
    \put(1.7262304,1.71616192){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{minipage}{0.13917663\unitlength}\raggedright \end{minipage}}}%
    \put(0.72001973,0.44786182){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ \alpha $}}%
    \put(1.46134596,1.29414276){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{minipage}{0.12346308\unitlength}\raggedright \end{minipage}}}%
    \put(0.43543939,0.06447172){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ x_0 $}}%
    \put(1.60725699,1.2716948){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{minipage}{0.20427537\unitlength}\raggedright \end{minipage}}}%
    \put(0.59936523,0.06444614){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{$ x $}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=3]{minimal_figure.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

And the result is

[image]

Comment: Move the entire `wrapfigure` environment to the start of the paragraph, rather than the placing it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) alludes to the placement of the `wrapfigure` (or `wraptable`) environment within your code in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) (section **1 Placement and Floating**):

> When floating, LaTeX tries to apply these rules. More specifically, a floated wrapping environment will only begin...
>
> - at the beginning of a paragraph,
> - ...

And, even though a paragraph is read in as a whole from a TeX perspective, you need to place the appropriate `wrap*` environment at the start of the paragraph, not the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{6.7cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{example-image}%
  \caption{Name of the figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.

\end{document}
```